# Simple Conditions on Partial Derivative Yielding Smoothness

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbf R}$
Let $f:\R^2\to \R^2$ be a differentiable function and assume that we have

$$\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1} = \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2}\qquad \text{and}\qquad \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2} = -\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1}$$

at all points in $\R^2$.

Then we know that $f$ is infinitely differentiable. This we can do by thinking of $f$ as a map from $\mathbf C$ to $\mathbf C$ which is differentibale in the real sense and satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations. Thus $f$ is holomorphic and therefore all partial derivatives at all points of $\R^2$ exist, showing that $f$ is smooth.

> *But is there a non-complex analytical way to do this?*

Such a proof is desirable for two reasons:

1) It will improve our understanding of real differentiability.

2) There may be generalizations for functions $f:\R^n\to\R^n$ which are differentiable once, and satisfy some conditions on low order partial derivatives which force smoothness. Such a proof may suggest a general formulation in higher dimensions and lead the way for a general proof.

Also, if you know any relevant literature then please post it here. Thank you.

Comment: One can show directly from the equations you wrote, that the real and imaginary parts of a holomorphic function - i.e. $f_1$ and $f_2$ -  are both harmonic. Then one uses analycity of harmonic functions.

Comment: @OlesWohnzimmer I didn't know that harmonic functions are analytic. So basically the thing boils down to showing that second partial derivatives exist.

Comment: @OlesWohnzimmer Do you know of any generalization to dimensions higher than 2? Thank you.

Comment: Harmonicity generalizes to higher dimensions by the condition that the sum of all second partial derivatives vanish. You could also look into higher dimensional complex analysis, i.e. complex analysis in multiple variables.